# Making Soap Requests to a wsdl URL using python-zeep

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl, zeep

Im trying to make a SOAP request and running into a couple of issues and I would need your help in resolving the error

```
from zeep import Client
client = Client(wsdl='http://<placeholder>/<serviceholder>.svc?wsdl')
response = client.service.MethodName(secret_code,secret_key,data.__str__())
```

and getting the following error

```
**zeep.exceptions.XMLSyntaxError: The XML returned by the server does not contain a valid {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope root element. The root element found is HTML**
```

I need 2 inputs,

1. The MethodName(secret_code,secret_key,`data.__str__()`) actually needs `data.ToString()` as that from c#. Am I even right to use this `__str__` in python or should I use something else?
   ( Just tell me the equivalent method of ToString() in python
2. Please tell me why Im getting that zeep.exception!

It would really mean a lot as I can't even sleep or resolve this error. Im so stuck! please help

Thanks in advance